# New menu does not appear in admin panel - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I was creating a custom menu to the Admin panel on Magento 2.

The code of menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Formation_Jobs::job_head" title="Jobs" module="Formation_Jobs" sortOrder="100" parent="Magento_Backend::content" resource="Formation_Jobs::job_head" />
        <add id="Formation_Jobs::department" title="Departments" module="Formation_Jobs" sortOrder="10" parent="Formation_Jobs::job_head" action="jobs/department" resource="Formation_Jobs::job" />
        <add id="Formation_Jobs::job" title="Jobs" module="Formation_Jobs" sortOrder="20" parent="Formation_Jobs::job_head" action="jobs/job" resource="Formation_Jobs::job" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

The structure of my folders (Module work perfectly) :

[image]

But the problem is I can't see the custom menu on my Admin Panel
[image]

Is there any solution?

PS: I use `setup:upgrade` and `cache:flush` && `setup:di:compile` and still not work

PS 2: I try to make an error on `menu.xml` ( don't close a tag ) and when I lunch `setup:upgrade`, I didn't get any error

Comment: does the user have the resource?

Comment: router id ?????

Comment: is the module enabled?

Comment: I've tested your code. I changed the module name `Formation_Jobs` to my own module `Vendor_Module`. After that it worked fine. Maybe you can test it in another custom module. Also, check your own module for spell mistakes. Maybe thats the reason it doesnt work.

Comment: @PhilippSander yes sir, the module is enabled

Comment: I try to make an error on `menu.xml` ( don't close a tag ) and when I lunch `setup:upgrade`, I didn't get any error

Comment: Did the module have a different name before? You could try to remove the module form the database (table: `setup_module`) & run the commands: `setup:upgrade`, `setup:di:compile`, `setup:static-content:deploy -f` and `cache:flush` in that order. With these steps you reinstall the module. As I said earlier, the code in menu.xml is fine. It looks like a module name somewhere is'nt correct. Please check all your code for spelling faults in the module name.

Comment: I try to make an error on a exiting module on vendor and after that when I fix the error it's work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a test module with the same name as yours. So check for namespaces. This works good:

> app/code/Formation/Jobs/ect/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Formation_Jobs" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Formation/Jobs/registration.php

```
<?php
/* file: app/code/Speak/StockImporter/registration.php  */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Formation_Jobs',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Formation/Jobs/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Formation_Jobs::job_head" title="Jobs" module="Formation_Jobs" sortOrder="100" parent="Magento_Backend::content" resource="Formation_Jobs::job_head" />
        <add id="Formation_Jobs::department" title="Departments" module="Formation_Jobs" sortOrder="10" parent="Formation_Jobs::job_head" action="jobs/department" resource="Formation_Jobs::job" />
        <add id="Formation_Jobs::job" title="Jobs" module="Formation_Jobs" sortOrder="20" parent="Formation_Jobs::job_head" action="jobs/job" resource="Formation_Jobs::job" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, the XML is very sensible, and I copied it from a website and something was on it for that it doesn't work, I write it from scratch and it work